# Copying a project to a new folder in SVN while maintaining diffs of the original project in crucible

Tags: svn, branch, diff, atlassian-crucible

I have the following SVN java project structure within a repo:

- Artifact folder 1

  - branches

    - dev

      - Project 1
- Artifact folder 2

  - branches

    - stable

I want to copy Project 1 from `Artifact folder 1/branches/dev/Project 1` to `Artifact folder 2/branches/stable`.

I want to copy it in such a manner that I am able to see the diffs in Project 1 since it was branched when I create a crucible review for it from `Artifact folder 2/branches/stable`. Is this possible?

Currently, I am just copying the project to the new location and when I add the commit it shows up all the files without showing the diffs it would show if I created a review from the original location.

Apologies if this has been answered before, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `svn copy`. For clarification purposes, branches and tags are both results of `svn copy`, in which the history is brought along with it.

So for your case, what you're going to want to do is a server side copy. So for your particular scenario you would want to use:

`svn copy "repo/URL/to/Artifact folder 1/branches/dev/Project 1" "repo/URL/to/Artifact folder 2/branches/stable/Project 1" -m "Enter a log message"`

Since you manually copied the files to `stable`, svn isn't smart enough to know where it originally came from. As far it knows, those files have never been written before in human history. However if you perform an svn copy, that particular revision acts as a *pointer* to the new location.

---

This is more of a side note, I would try to avoid spacing as much as possible in file structures. Especially on certain OSs such as Linux, where naming conventions are already strict enough as is (you have to use correct capitalization, slashes need to be correct, etc.). It removes the need for excessive quotes in your commands.

Comment: When I add the new commit (the result of `svn copy` above) as a diff in `crucible` it still doesn't show me the history. It just shows a new commit and shows no change. Is there another way of adding revision in crucible?